# .htaccess: RewriteRule not Working using just the value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've done a lot of research to solve this problem but I still can't figure out why it won't work. Initially I had Re-written my urls to add a `.html` but I want to change that and keep them simple without any suffix.

**Here's an example of original link**

`http://www.howwe.biz/artist?a=eddy-kenzo`

I used the rule below to change the link above and add a suffix **.html**

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /artist?a=$1 [L]`

The result is : `http://www.howwe.biz/eddy-kenzo.html`

I want to rewrite the original link to something like this

```
http://www.howwe.biz/eddy-kenzo
```

I've tried using `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /artist?a=$1 [L]` to achieve that but I get a horrible server error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@howwe.biz and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

The **eddy-kenzo** in the url is the value. What's odd is that if I add the name which in this case is **a**, it works. See below:

`RewriteRule ^a/([^/]*)$ /artist?a=$1 [L]` is valid for `http://www.howwe.biz/a/bebe-cool` but I need this like this `http://www.howwe.biz/bebe-cool`

What is it that am doing wrong. Your help will be much appreciated.

Sorry if this was tl;dr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1redirect "/artist?a=foo" to "/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /artist\?a=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,L,R]

#skip the rule if the request is for dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #skip the rule if the request is for file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #rewrite anyother request  to "/artist?a=" 
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /artist?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

Your rule

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /artist?a=$1 [L]` failed because it is rewriting any request to target url unconditionally , the target url matches the pattern and it rewrites to itself. You rule will work with the following conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /artist?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: A big thanks to you @Starkeen ... I didn't have to change a thing in your code and it works perfectly.

I've had this problem for months and now it's solved! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule \/(.*)? /artist?a=$1
```

It takes everything from behind the last / to the end, and adds it to $1.